# Problem with multiple div and onclick button with id parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make a notification system for a school project, jQuery is not allowed! Each time there is a notification I'm creating a div with an onclick button to acknowledge the notification with the id as parameter.

Then my function JavaScript get the div and pass the notification to a 1 status in SQL with ajax and finally close the div. When I only have one notification it's working perfectly but when there is multiple div, my script seem unable to close each notification and I need to refresh my page to close each div.

My code:

```
 foreach($notifs as $notif){
                            $id = $notif["id"]; ?> 
                             <div id="notifAlert">
                                <p><?= $notif["content"]; ?><br> <button onclick="seenNotif(<?= $id; ?>)">OK</button></p>
                            </div>
                    <?php  } } ?>
```

```
function seenNotif(idNotif){
    console.log(idNotif);

        const divNotif = document.getElementById("notifAlert");
        const footer = document.getElementById("foot");


            const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState === 4){
                footer.removeChild(divNotif);
            }

        };

        req.open("GET", "notifStatut.php?idNotif="+idNotif);
        req.send();

        
}
```

```
require ("functions.php");

$idNotif = $_GET["idNotif"];

    $connection = connectDB();

    $query = $connection->prepare("UPDATE notifications SET statut = :statut WHERE id = :idNotif");
    $query->execute([
        "statut" => 1,
        "idNotif" => $idNotif
    ]);
```

Comment: Hello! You cannot have multiple elements with the same id attribute. I suggest you use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, id's have to be unique.
The simplest solution is to change

in PHP

`<div id="notifAlert">` to

`<div id="notifAlert<?= $id ?>">`

(add `$id` to the id to make it unique)

and in javascript

`document.getElementById("notifAlert")` to

`document.getElementById("notifAlert"+idNotif)`

Th should get you the div you want.

Comment: That was it! Thank you, it now work perfectly ! :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more in depth answer then my comment.

You cannot have multiple HTML elements with the same id, they need to be unique. I suggest you use a class instead.

```
foreach($notifs as $notif){
    $id = $notif["id"]; ?> 
    <div class="notifAlert">
    <p><?= $notif["content"]; ?><br> <button onclick="seenNotif(<?= $id; ?>)">OK</button></p>
    </div>
<?php  } } ?>
```

You will then also need to change your javascript

```
function seenNotif(idNotif){
    console.log(idNotif);

    const divNotif = document.getElementsByClassName("notifAlert");
    const footer = document.getElementById("foot");

    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4){
            for (var i = 0; i < divNotif.length; i++)
                footer.removeChild(divNotif[i]);
        }
    };

    req.open("GET", "notifStatut.php?idNotif="+idNotif);
    req.send();    
}
```

Comment: Hello!! Thanks for that, but it seem that the problem is still the same... When I inspect the notif div, multiple div with different id are in the onclick parameter but when I click on the button the same id is showing with the console.log

Comment: Wouldn't `for (var i = 0; i < divNotif.length; i++)` remove **all** the div's with the click of one button? I suppose OP only wants the div removed where the button was clicked.

Comment: Apparently no! Still the same behavior, what do you mean by OP?

Comment: OP is short for Original Poster, that's you :)